# Creating a container for content using div

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am building a small page, I have a div content wrapper and within that I have several div that contain the actual content. Only for some reason my div that I want to hold the text isn't holding it. Ultimately I am trying to add a little space between the photo and the text. Notice how the first line of the text is spaced from the image but the rest adjoin it. Here is the code:

```css
#content_wrap {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 50px 0px 0px;
}
#content_photo {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}
#content_desc {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 100px;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}
#aphoto {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="content_wrap">
  <div id="content_photo">
    <img id="aphoto" src="//placehold.it/100?text=Image" align="left">
  </div>
  <div id="content_desc">A whole bunch of random text. A whole bunch of random text. A whole bunch of random text. A whole bunch of random text. A whole bunch of random text.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's a lot of space right? Your question is totally unclear. Okay, now I get it.

Comment: Added an answer. Does it work?

Comment: looks like it does. can you explain what it's doing and why it worked?

Comment: Yes, I have give a float left, to both of them, so that they are in line with each other. I have given a margin right to the image, so that there's a space between the text and the image. I also gave a width for the right side, minus the width of the image and the whole content, so that it correctly resides.

Comment: I believe the alternate answer in this case is simpler and more direct. +1 though

Comment: Okay, whatever you feel. `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `display: inline;` instead of `display: inline-block;`. To cast the element as a block means you will have to manually specify the width of the container or the block will assume 100% of the parents width thus putting the element on its own line.

Here's an example:

```css
.content_wrap {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 50px 0px 0px;
}

.content_photo {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
}

.content_desc {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 536px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px
}

.aphoto {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div class="content_wrap">
    <div class="content_photo">
      <img class="aphoto" src="https://place-hold.it/100" align="left">
    </div>
  <div class="content_desc">A whole bunch of random text. A whole bunch of random text. A whole bunch of random text. A whole bunch of random text. A whole bunch of random text.</div>
</div>
<div class="content_wrap">
  <div class="content_photo">
    <img class="aphoto" src="https://place-hold.it/100" align="left">
  </div>
  <div class="content_desc">A whole bunch of random text. A whole bunch of random text. A whole bunch of random text. A whole bunch of random text. A whole bunch of random text.</div>
</div>
</center>
```

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit on why `inline-block` vs `inline`. when you say specify width you mean of the div containing the text?

Comment: Because you have a multi lined element (a bunch of text) the padding does not render onto the next line as technically the overflowed text (the text that has wrapped onto the new line) isn't actually on a new line thus the padding is only applied to the top line and the rest is ignored (perceived as one line). And yes, defining a block automatically assigned the width to auto (the width of the parent block) which does not allow for any other elements to be rendered beside it. An alternative to this is using a table layout that can render inline but also have a dynamic width.

Comment: understood, makes sense. also: i noticed that the text doesn't align to the top of the image, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: It does. If you place a border around the content you'll see the element is aligned with the image. This is padding of the font. I suppose you could increase the margin of the image to lower it a few pixels but technically this wont align it as some letters within the font are bigger than others. e.g 'a' is smaller than 'L' (aL) so a full row of 'a' (aaaaa) might align with the image but a full row of 'L' (LLLL) or mixed (LaaaLaa) will surpass the image position thus ruining the illusion of alignment. Only thing I can think of is to use a font that has each character the same height?

Answer (score 1):

To add the space to the right side, I use `float` and `margin`:

```css
#content_wrap {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 50px 0px 0px;
}
#content_photo {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
#content_desc {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 535px;
}
#aphoto {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="content_wrap">
  <div id="content_photo">
    <img id="aphoto" src="//placehold.it/100?text=Image" />
  </div>
  <div id="content_desc">A whole bunch of random text. A whole bunch of random text. A whole bunch of random text. A whole bunch of random text. A whole bunch of random text.</div>
</div>
```

The above code gives me something like this:

[image: preview]

Answer (score 0):

you could also just apply flex to the wrapping div

```css
#content_wrap {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 50px 0px 0px;
  display: flex;
}
#content_photo {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
}
#content_desc {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 100px;
  position: relative;
}
#aphoto {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="content_wrap">
  <div id="content_photo">
    <img id="aphoto" src="//placehold.it/100?text=Image" align="left">
  </div>
  <div id="content_desc">A whole bunch of random text. A whole bunch of random text. A whole bunch of random text. A whole bunch of random text. A whole bunch of random text.</div>
</div>
```